# Name of theorem for $\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \right] = \mathbb{E}[N] \mathbb{E}[X_1]$

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, summation, random-variables, expectation

Suppose we have identically distributed variables $(X_n)_n$ and some random variable $N$ which takes values in $\mathbb{N}$. Then under certain conditions we have:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \right] = \mathbb{E}[N] \mathbb{E}[X_1],
$$
but where can I find this theorem and does it have a name?

Comment: Depending on context, (I think) this is similar to one of Wald's identities.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#Basic_version

Comment: THis is the answer I was looking for, if you post it in an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}$ is called a compound random variable. It is the sum of  a random number of iid random variables. In particular, if the random variable $N$ is Poisson distributed, then the random variable $\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}$ is called a compound Poisson random variable.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for the answer. But the theorem I was looking for is Wald's equation as noted in the comments.

Comment: @HolyMonk, you can this result in Ross's Introduction to Probability Models.